# Customize default message djangorestframework-simplejwt retrieved when the user is not active?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, djoser

I'm using Django==4.0.3 ,djangorestframework==3.13.1 and djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.1.0 and djoser==2.1.0
I have used djoser to authenticate, and all works fine.

When the user is not active yet, the response is same as when user enter wrong password

```
{"detail":"No active account found with the given credentials"}
```

I need to customize this response. I have checked this message inside a dictionary in the class TokenObtainSerializer

```
   default_error_messages = {
    'no_active_account': _('No active account found with the given credentials')
}
```

have tried to override this class with no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to override the validate() method of TokenObtainSerializer as follows:

```py
serializers.py

class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainSerailizer):
    def validate():
        ...
        authenticate_kwargs = {
            self.username_field: attrs[self.username_field],
            'password': attrs['password'],
        }
        try:
            authenticate_kwargs['request'] = self.context['request']
        except KeyError:
            pass
        self.user = authenticate(**authenticate_kwargs)
        print(self.user)
        if self.user is None or not self.user.is_active:
            self.error_messages['no_active_account'] = _(
                'No active account found with the given credentials') # --> Change this error message for what you want to replace this with.
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(
                self.error_messages['no_active_account'],
                'no_active_account',
            )
        return super().validate(attrs)
```

Now update your serializer class to use the custom serializer as:

```py
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(CustomTokenObtainPairSerailizer):
    pass
```